# What is the value of self in a Rails model and why aren't obvious instance methods available?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, self

I have a custom accessor method in my rails 3.1.6 app that assigns a value to an attribute, even if the value is not present.The my_attr attribute is a serialized Hash which should be merged with the given value unless a blank value is specified, in which case it will set the current value to a blank value. (There are added checks to make sure the values are what they should be, but are removed for brevity, as they are not part of my question.) My setter is defined as:

```
def my_attr=(new_val)
  cur_val = read_attribute(:my_attr)  #store current value

  #make sure we are working with a hash, and reset value if a blank value is given
  write_attribute(:my_attr, {}) if (new_val.nil? || new_val.blank? || cur_val.blank?)

  #merge value with new 
  if cur_val.blank?
    write_attribute(:my_attr, new_val)
  else
    write_attribute(:my_attr,cur_val.deep_merge(new_val))
  end
  read_attribute(:my_attr)
end
```

This code works well as-is, but not when I use self.write_attribute(). I then get the following error:

```
NoMethodError:
       private method `write_attribute' called for #<MyModel:0x00000004f10528>
```

My questions are thus: It seems more logical to have write_attribute available to an instance, so why is it only available to the class and **not** to the instance? Is there something lacking in my fundamental knowledge of *self* in Ruby or Rails (or both)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Inside of an instance method `self` is that instance. However, when you call a method with explicit receiver, then ruby's visibility control kicks in and forbids invocation of the private method.

```
class Foo
  def implicit
    self # => #<Foo:0x007fc019091060>
    private_method
  end

  def explicit
    self # => #<Foo:0x007fc019091060>
    self.private_method
  end

  private
  def private_method
    "bar"
  end
end

f = Foo.new
f.implicit # => "bar"
f.explicit # => 
# ~> -:9:in `explicit': private method `private_method' called for #<Foo:0x007fc019091060> (NoMethodError)
# ~>    from -:25:in `<main>'
```

If you want to call private methods, use implicit receiver or `send`.

```
self.send :private_method
```

### Update

An excerpt from a [ruby metaprogramming book](http://pragprog.com/book/ppmetr/metaprogramming-ruby).

> #### ￼What private Really Means
>
> Now that you know about self, you can cast a new light over Ruby’s private keyword. Private methods are governed by a single simple rule: you cannot call a private method with an explicit receiver. In other words, every time you call a private method, it must be on the implicit receiver—self. Let’s see a corner case:
>
> ```
> class C
>   def public_method
>     self.private_method 
>   end
>   private
>   def private_method; end
> end
> C.new.public_method
>
> ⇒ NoMethodError: private method ‘private_method' called [...]
> ```
>
> You can make this code work by removing the self keyword.
>
> This contrived example shows that private methods come from two rules working together: first, you need an explicit receiver to call a method on an object that is not yourself, and second, private methods can be called only with an implicit receiver. Put these two rules together, and you’ll see that you can only call a private method on yourself. You can call this the “private rule.”
>
> You could find Ruby’s private methods perplexing—especially if you come from Java or C#, where private behaves very differently. When you’re in doubt, just go back to the private rule, and everything will make sense. Can object x call a private method on object y if the two objects share the same class? The answer is no, because no matter which class you belong to, you still need an explicit receiver to call another object’s method. Can you call a private method that you inherited from a superclass? The answer is yes, because you don’t need an explicit receiver to call inherited methods on yourself.