# Difference between self.class and class << self

Tags: ruby, class

Trying to find out how **private** and **protected** works when used on class methods I came with this code from [some other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11143850/253098):

```
class Bang
    def instance_bang
      self.class.class_bang
    end

    protected
    def self.class_bang
      puts "bang"
    end
end
```

Calling **instance_bang** from an instance of Bang works as expected, however I cannot understand what is different in the following code when I take the approach of using **class << self**.

```
class Bang
  def instance_bang
    self.class.class_bang
  end

  class << self
    protected 
    def class_bang
      puts "bang"
    end
  end
end
```

To me, both pieces of code seems to be the same, but the second one fails with **NoMethodError** claiming that **class_bang** is protected.

Comment: One thing you might find confusing is `self.` at the beginning of `self.class.class_bang` in the instance method `instance_bang`.  It is not needed, because if no receiver is given, `self` is assumed. If you're unsure, try it with `class.class_bang`. in IRB or PRY.

Comment: Just tried with 2.1.0 and got a syntax error https://gist.github.com/fgarcia/8382526#file-gistfile1-txt-L3-L5

Comment: @CarySwoveland You need to write `self.class.class_bang` as it is. If you do `class.class_bang`, MRI sees it as a `class` keyword. So error you will be getting.

Comment: I stand corrected.  I'll have to have another look in the morning, with fresh eyes.

Comment: That's interesting.  @Arup, I do not dispute that `self.` is needed to tell Ruby you are referring to the method, not the keyword, but why isn't Ruby smart enough to know that, considering that `class` is chained to `class_bang`?  `self.` is needed, for example, when followed by a setter method, to distinguish it from a local variable, but I don't understand the need here, though this is probably not the place to dig into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second chunk of code, protected is used to specify visibility of methods of Bang class. But 'def self.class_bang' defines a method on the singleton class of Bang, so the protected key will not apply for the method.

In the first chunk of code, you open singleton class of Bang, so protected is used to specify visibility of methods of singleton class of Bang, this means protected will apply for class_bang method. That is why you get the error.

For more information, read this: http://blog.jayfields.com/2006/11/ruby-protected-class-methods.html

Comment: so that's why! But, does it mean the only way to call Bang.class_bang within Bang#instance_bang is by using the send method?

Comment: Yes, because you're not calling a protected method inside its class body or inside its subclass body. Bang is an instance of its Singleton Class, not subclass of its Singleton Class.